# AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE AuditEvent remote address is missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I'm using SpringBoot framework. Bellow is result of default actuator event auditing. For some reason I got two different type of audit events

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-28T14:26:58.877Z",
    "principal": "admin",
    "type": "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
    "data": {
        "message": "Bad credentials",
        "type": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
        "remoteAddress": "10.12.1.25"
    }
}
```

and here is another

```
{
        "timestamp": "2020-04-28T10:29:36.583Z",
        "principal": "adminf",
        "type": "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
        "data": {
            "message": "Bad credentials",
            "type": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException"
        }
    }
```

I can not explain why remote address is missing in the second one.